# How to collect and iterate over all items in Observable Collections of different types?

Tags: c#, linq, observablecollection

I have several ObservableCollections containing generic types such as:

`ObservableCollection<MyViewModel<Color>> ColorVMs`

`ObservableCollection<MyViewModel<Sound>> SoundVMs`

I need to:

1. When given a type of `MyViewModel` check if it is in any of those collections based on a property
2. Remove the element from the relevant collection
3. Clear all collections

The `MyViewModel` class does not inherit from anything.

Is there a way for me to make a list of ObservableCollections so I can loop over them anonymously rather than duplicating code each time like this:

```
if (this.ColorVMs.Remove(this.ColorVMs.Single(i => i.Parameter.Id == oldParameter.Id)));
if (this.SoundVMs.Remove(this.ColorVMs.Single(i => i.Parameter.Id == oldParameter.Id)));
```

and this
Currently I have to list them all out like this:

```
    ColorVMs.Clear();
    SoundVMs.Clear();
```

Comment: How does `Color` relate to `Sound`? Do they inherit from the same base?

Comment: @PeterCsala no - they could be types just like float and string.

Comment: Maybe it is a silly question but have you thought about `ColorVMS.Cast<MyViewModel<object>>().Union(SoundVMS.Cast<MyViewModel<object>>())`? Or you can define an `IIdentifyable` interface, which exposes the `Id` property.